# Batch START command just start a blank command window not run my script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I am working on a project where I need to start another batch file, **Task Options.bat** from this batch file, **Task.bat** in the **same directory**, but not close or pause the original file, so this is the script of **Task.bat**

```
@ECHO off
TITLE Task
START /D %~dp0 "Task Options.bat"
:loop
TASKLIST /FI "MEMUSAGE gt 20000"
timeout 10 >nul
cls
goto loop
```

Other lines are irrelevant but the third line of code: When I run the file, it just opens a blank cmd window that titled "Task Options.bat". There are codes in the **Task Options.bat** file so if it is being ran it would output something. So where I did wrong?

Comment: First quotes in a START command are the window title. See `start /?`.

Comment: Checkout the help for `START` - `help start`. The following should work: `START "Task" /D . "Task Options.bat"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@ECHO off
TITLE Task
START "Task Options" /D "%~dp0" %ComSpec% /k "Task Options.bat"
:loop
TASKLIST /FI "MEMUSAGE gt 20000"
timeout 10 >nul
cls
goto loop
```

Note that you may want to change the /k to /c if you want the Options window to go away after the options.bat script runs.  Use /k until you've got all the bugs worked out.

Your version did not work because you had the command line arguments all mixed up. This sets the console window title to Options, the starting directory path to the same directory the script is in, uses the %COMSPEC% variable to find the correct cmd.exe file and hands it the Options.bat script file name to execute.

Comment: If this helped, please mark it as the answer so we can get it off of the unanswered list.

Comment: It's an okay answer, but you should explain _why_ it works so that they don't have to ask the same question tomorrow.

Comment: @Mofi, thanks!  The space after the /D is allowed and specified in the start help but probably not required.